# The web page could not be accessed Coded UI Error

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am running a Coded UI test that clicks a hyperlink, for example, "Home" then goes off and does a few different things on the web page, then tries to click the exact same "Home" link and an error is thrown saying

> The web page could not be accessed. If the page is refreshing, please
>   wait until the page refreshes and then perform actions on it.

Now I get this when I am stepping through the test, so I know at the point this link is trying to be clicked the page is not refreshing. Digging through the UITest error logs I see this line every time before the browser refresh error is thrown:

> E, 6468, 13, 2013/10/18, 15:08:47.406, 271797587803, QTAgent32_40.exe,
>   IEDOM : EnsureValid failed for html node: A, 52

I have compared the uitest mappings for this link and the properties are all identical, also the page html is identical. 
I am running in IE10, KB2879017. VS2012 4 RC.

Any idea's what's causing this to happen?

NOTE: WaitForControlReady() does nothing to stop this from happening. Also a hard coded Playback.Wait() doesn't help here either.

Failing line of code, this works the first time, but not the second time it is executed in a test.

```
this.UIWindow.UIDocument.UIHomeHyperlink.WaitForControlReady();
Mouse.Click(this.UIWindow.UIDocument.UIHomeHyperlink);
```

Remember that the search properties being used for the UIHomeHyperlink mapped control are the exact same the second time these lines are executed. Mouse.Click() execution is when the "Web page not available" error is thrown in VS2012.

Comment: I think it would be best if you posted your code.

Comment: Added the lines of code I am executing, the first line executes as expected, the page is fully loaded and carries on to the Mouse.Click() method.

Comment: Are the filterproperties the same? Are the windowtitles the same? Occasionally there is some session data that makes the "same" object actually different.

Comment: Window Titles and filter properties are the exact same, I have a similar test that never leaves the page, but needs to click the same button twice after selecting different rad buttons (no postbac here) and throws the same error. I would think if filter props were not correct I would just get a UITestControlNotFound exception, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some brainstorming and trial and error testing, came to the conclusion that mapped controls are holding onto properties after being found on a page. For some reason those properties weren't matching up exactly with the page properties on the second time around.

So a "solution" to this problem was to force a new up of the entire mapped UI___Window each time we enter the page. Coded UI prevents this in the designer file by checking if the control is null every time, if it is then the control is new'ed up. If not, then Coded UI uses the same control and it's properties from when it was first defined/discovered. Hope this helps anyone else that was having problems with this error.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Can you explain more about your "new up" idea? I'm just using a test generated in the UIMap.Designer.cs, and often when the test runs, it fails on Mouse.Click() for a button that is clearly on the page. It's the first time the button is encountered during the test. Possibly if the test runs once, works, and then runs again, this is where the 2nd encounter of the same control is happening as you describe. But are you saying: "new UIMap()" in some sense?

Comment: If you look at the generated Designer file you will see that the first time a control is accessed it is stored in a private variable. If you try and access it again it uses the value stored previously, occasionally causing problems finding the control. What I did is create a property of the map when I use it in my tests, each time that property is called it news up the map.
Example: MapObject.UITestControlObject, each time MapObject is called it news up that map, in a sense clearing out the stored controls the last time it was accessed.

Answer (score 0):

There also seems to be a bug in CodedUI when calling `.GetParent()` twice on the same object tree, which causes this exception to be thrown. We worked around it by determining the parent in another way.

On another workstation (W7) another exception was thrown when calling `.GetParent()` twice, something about that the IE version should be more than IE10 on 64bit versions of Windows, which was clearly nonsense, since the computer had IE11 installed.